# How is this pairing $\langle\,,\rangle$ defined of cocharacter and character of an algebraic group?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, characters

Let $G$ be a semisimple linear algebraic group. Let $X^*$ be the group of characters and $X_*$ be the group of cocharacters. Then I know that there exists a pairing $\langle\,,\rangle : X^*(G) \times X_*(G) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, defined by $\langle \lambda, \chi\rangle = \lambda \circ \chi$.

Let $P$ be a parabolic subgroup of $G$, $M$ its Levi factor and $N$ the split component (so $P$ is the semidirect product of $M$ and $N$, $N$ being a normal subgroup of $G$). Let $a = X_*(N) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{R}$. 
How does the pairing $\langle\,,\rangle$ work for (or generalise to) $a \times X^*(P)$?

(I think the pairing in the first paragraph generalises to this case somehow..? because it is used without explanation in the article I was reading, and I wasn't sure how this was defined. I would greatly appreciate any explanation of how this works.. Thank you very much.)

Comment: Are you sure you want to consider characters and cocharacters of the group itself? For example, $N$ will in general not be abelian, so tensoring its cocharacters with something over the integers is not really meaningful (and it is true that there is a pairing for the semisimple group, but for example in the case where it is simply connected, its group of characters is trivial, which makes it fairly uninteresting).

Comment: The tensor product $X_*(N) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{R}$ is definitely what they do... (without explanation) and I don't understand exactly what they mean by it. It does make sense to consider $\lambda^m$ for each $\lambda \in X_*(N)$ and $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. So maybe they mean to tensor each $\mathbb{Z}$-module generated by the individual elements in $X_*(N)$?

Comment: Could you include which paper this is, as that might help figure out what is meant.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Sure, it is this paper right here: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01233436 . The tensor product in question is line -4 on page 426, and the pairing is considered on the following page line 8.

Comment: You seem to have linked to an erratum for the paper rather than the paper itself. And I unfortunately do not have access to the paper since I am not at uni right now.

Comment: Oops, yes this was the link: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01393904

Comment: @JohnnyT. When $G$ is semisimple, $X^*(G)$ is trivial. When $P$ is a parabolic subgroup of $G$, then its Levi factor $M$ is in general not semisimple, so $X^*(M)$ is OK. By "split component" they are referring not to the unipotent radical, but to a subtorus inside $M$.